# error when accessing a local host from a docker image

Tags: docker

I have Mamp installed on my Mac, and a docker image.

I'm trying to access from my docker image to a virtual host URL.

LOCAL URL MAMP: http//:testurl:8888

How can I do it?

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: testimage
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "444:443"
networks:
  - dockernet

environment:
- REDIS_HOST=redishost
- CONFIG_SERVER_URI=http://config.dev.com/
- MAMP_URL=http//:testurl:8888

volumes:
- /Users/david/www/test/project:/var/www/:rw
- ../logs:/var/log/apache2/:rw
- ../ssl:/etc/apache2/ssl/:rw

extra_hosts:
  platform.test.dev.com: 127.0.0.1
  order.test.dev.com: 127.0.0.1
  partner.test.dev.com: 127.0.0.1

networks:
    dockernet:
        external: true
```

Error in docker image when I try to access the url of my mamp with port 8888.

{"code":500,"message":"cURL error 7: Failed to connect to dev.pag-api-ssb.com port 8888: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"}
Thx

Comment: Enable access to port 8888 from ports or access from 80 not 8888

Comment: from dockerfile, EXPOSE 8888? If not, how can I do it?

Comment: In your docker-compose add to ports  ```ports: - "8888:8888" ``` in service web.

Comment: that port I am already using it for my mamp server, therefore it will not let me use it

Comment: it has been working for me including extra_host the url with the ip of my local